# How does std :: current_exception work?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following example:

```
class myclass
{
public:

    void f() const
    {
        std :: cout << "Hello from myclass!" << std :: endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std :: exception_ptr x;

    try
    {
        throw myclass();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        x = std :: current_exception();
    }

    try
    {
        std :: rethrow_exception(x);
    }
    catch(const myclass & n)
    {
        n.f();
    }
}
```

Here I throw an object of class `myclass` and use `std :: current_exception()` in the `catch(...)` block to get a `std :: exception_ptr`. Later I use `std :: rethrow_exception` to get the exception thrown again and I catch it, this time with `catch(const myclass &)`, that allows me to, e.g., call `f()` and get `Hello from myclass!` printed out.

Now. I kind of imagine how I could implement something similar to `std :: exception_ptr`: a pointer to a base class, from which a template wrapper for each possible type inherits, and some `rethrow` virtual method that allows to throw again the exception. So far so good.

Now, how does `std :: current_exception()` work? How is it implemented? I tried to inspect it using my Xcode but I got a nice flashing question mark: `?`. Is this some kind of primitive in C++11? Like, e.g., `decltype` or `sizeof`? Or is there another way to access the exception hidden in that `catch(...)`?

For example, is there a way to just *print out* an exception, whatever it is? Something like:

```
template <typename type> void printme(const type & exception)
{
    try
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std :: cout << /* SOME MAGIC HERE */ << std :: endl;
    }
}
```

I guess that `std :: current_exception()` would be using some similar way to access the exception, make a copy of it, and instantiate an appropriate `std :: exception_ptr` that can be later rethrown.

So am I missing something? I tried something trivial like `catch(auto x)` but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: `catch(auto&&)` is actually a very nice idea for the future.

Comment: @DeiDei I would argue that exceptions should always be caught by `const &`.

Comment: The standard library often uses compiler support to implement stuff, aka Black Magic. I really like the idea of having a `catch(auto)`, looks much better than `catch(...)` IMO.

Comment: @DeiDei, not feasible, would require template-like instantiation for every potentially throwable type.

Comment: `current_exception()` seems **not** to be for inspecting the exception, but handling it as described in the answer (and probably working with promises & futures). If you came here for `catch (...) { msg = std::current_exception()->what(); }` there's no such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `std::exception_ptr` there was [`boost::exception_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/exception_ptr.html) that attempts to implement this functionality without direct language support and consequently requires more boilerplate code to work. With Boost, you have to wrap the exception at the point of `throw`  with [`boost::enable_current_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/enable_current_exception.html) and throw the wrapper instead. I have not actually studied the implementation, but I imagine that the wrapper's copy constructor sets a thread-local pointer to point to itself (`throw` must copy its argument) which [`boost::current_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/exception/doc/current_exception.html) then retrieves (possibly copying the exception to free store first, so that it can outlive the `catch` block). For `catch (T x)` to still work the wrapper has to wrap the original exception by inheriting from it, which makes it impossible to use with primitive types.

Another way is to copy the original, set the thread-local pointer to point to the copy and throw the original. This way works for any throwable type but `current_exception` would refer to a different instance than the one used o initialize the `catch` parameter.

Now `std::exception_ptr` has direct language support and does not have to jump through hoops or do excessive copying to archive this but the basic idea is that same: store the exception in a type-erased container that can rethrow it at the point of throw and point to that.

Comment: I see. So `std :: current_exception` *does* have compiler support. Interesting. I wonder, is this the simplest operation one can do to handle something in `catch(...)`? I mean, they have already had to update their compiler to implement `std :: current_exception`: why not give more freedom on how to use it? In my mind, the simplest operation here that needs compiler support is to actually get the exception object from the `catch(...)`. The part where the object is copied, wrapped in an object that offers the possibility to rethrow it... it can be trivially implemented in C++..

Comment: I mean, to get `std :: current_exception` they must have *already* done something like `catch(const auto &)`. Why not provide us directly with that feature, instead of forcing us to go through the whole `exception_ptr` thing? What, for example, if I had some `template <typename type> void handle_exception(const type &)` function that I would like to call from my `catch(...)` block? Is it impossible to do such a thing? And why would they forbid it?

Comment: @MatteoMonti indeed it is impossible because it would require instantiating `handle_exception` for all the exception types it is going to catch, which are not known until run-time.